# (PETSc with FEM) How can we set the boundary conditions (Dirichlet and neumann)?

Tags: finite-element-analysis, petsc

I need help for understanding the `PETSc` examples of finite element method with `SNES` nonlinear solver. Is there any good materials or sources to understand the examples? ***(I already read `PETSc` user manual, but there is no information which I need.)***

I will make a code which includes `rectangular geometry`, with `PetscFE` and `DMPlex` (for unstructured mesh). The code will treat the heat transfer equation with non-linear heat sources.

I want to select boundary conditions with two dirichlet condition

1. Upper and lower boundary on the rectangle.
2. Two neumann condition (right and left boundary on the rectangle).

**Example 12 of SNES**, user should define:

> `quadratic_u_2d` as exact solution (to improve the convergence of the
>   solution)
>
> `f_0` (integrand of test function term (which is related with load
>   vector 'f'))
>
> `f_bc_0` (boundary integrand of test function term (which is related
>   with flux 'g')) (I think, this may be boundary condition)
>
> `f_1` (integrand of test function gradient term (which is related with
>   u_x[d]))
>
> `f_bc_1` (boundary integrand of test function gradient term (it is zero,
>   I think, the term is not defined during weak formation of governing
>   equation))
>
> `g3` (integrand of test function gradient and basis function gradient
>   term) (I think that this term is fixed as 1 in any case)

But there is no way to set each boundary condition individually. Please give me some advise for better undertanding.

Thanks for reading my question..

Comment: please try to use formatting so that your question is presented is a nice manner which attracts the attention of the concerned users and defines/highlights our points

Answer (score 0):

I use Petsc in fluid flow problems with FVM method and I set the boundary conditions by modifying the matrix A and its corresponding RHS values.